# Why is (13 / 3 == 4) true?

Tags: java, division, integer-division

```
((13 / 3 == 4) == true)
```

why is this equals true? 
13/3 = 4.3333 and
4.333 is not equaled 4.
Is it about auto cast into an integer? and round?

I tested it in Java EE 8.

Comment: *Integer* division: `13 / 3` is an integer. Put *floating point* in order to get floating point value: `13.0 / 3.0 == 4.3333....`

Comment: That's because of integer math...

Comment: It's not rounded but the decimals after the point are truncated eg `(int)4.6` is still `4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you write `13 / 3` you have divided two integer, so the result is only int part, so `4`.

In this way you have the next condition `4 == 4` is `true`